# Meld issue with codification (one file in Chinese chars)

Tags: 16.04, diff

This is odd.  Meld has two text files which were generated by the same program on different dates.  One comes out fine but the other is unreadable.  The issue does not exist in the terminal.  I recently upgraded to 16.04.  Maybe that has something to do with this?

[image: Here is a screenshot of the issue]

update: as per comments one file is in ISO and the other in UTF-8.

Comment: Encoding, likely. One is probably UTF-8, the other, who knows? Run the `file` command on both files.

Comment: can you make this comment an answer and I will accept it.  I will say that I didn't have this issue is 12.04 and I seem to be having multiple encoding issues in 16.04 for what it is worth

Comment: in that case, you should probably amend the question to add more details so that the actual issue can be solved

Comment: done.  Feel free to make any change suggestions